# Simple Payment flow Paypal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

I have a form where a team signs up their players and then are transported to paypal to make a registration payment then I receive an IPN when everything is complete. I am doing a similar form and found that Paypal has changed a lot since I created that form.

Is there still a simple way to transfer to paypal, user pays, send back to success page?

It seems like now I have to send the user to paypal using SetExpressCheckout then Getting Payer Details Using GetExpressCheckoutDetails and then DoExpressCheckoutPayment. Am I making it too complicated? It seems I'll be bouncing a registrant around to a bunch of unnecessary pages just to get a payment for a single item. What is the simplest way to do this and still get an ipn to insert into my db? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well EC is the preferred option because its easier for the merchant, but you can use PayPal Standard as well. PayPal standard can be implemented simply as a button. Its pretty simple, but it does not use API calls; its just simply form data posted to PayPal, then PayPal sends you the confirmation of payment in the form of an IPN. the customer is not "forced" back to your site either.

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/paypal-payments-standard